# Apply() error in running MixSIAR in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

My below code is returning the error:
Error in apply(jags.1$BUGSoutput$sims.list$p.global, 2, getQuant) :
dim(X) must have a positive length

I am trying to get this code to run all ten models separately and then save them in the jags_mod_list.

```
 library(MixSIAR)
library(tidyr)
library(R2jags)
library(ggplot2)

#This is for Black bear Diet analysis


mix.filename = "/Users/elleryvincent/Desktop/ADFG Black Bear Stable Isotope/SI_Sp.csv"
source.filename <- "/Users/elleryvincent/Desktop/ADFG Black Bear Stable Isotope/Sources1_5_2021.csv"
discr.filename <- "/Users/elleryvincent/Desktop/ADFG Black Bear Stable Isotope/DV_SIDER_omnivore.csv"

n.mod <-10

mix <- vector("list", n.mod)
# Define each model
for (mod in 1:n.mod) {
  if (mod == 1) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = NULL,
                                fac_random = NULL,
                                fac_nested = NULL,  # Specify if factors are nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 2) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = "sex",
                                fac_random = FALSE,
                                fac_nested = FALSE,  # Specify if "sex" is nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 3) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = "class",
                                fac_random = FALSE,
                                fac_nested = FALSE,  # Specify if "class" is nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 4) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = "bait",
                                fac_random = FALSE,
                                fac_nested = FALSE,  # Specify if "bait" is nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 5) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = c("sex", "bait"),
                                fac_random = c(FALSE, FALSE),
                                fac_nested = c(FALSE, FALSE),  # Specify if factors are nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 6) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = "month",
                                fac_random = FALSE,
                                fac_nested = FALSE,  # Specify if "month" is nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 7) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = "wk2",
                                fac_random = FALSE,
                                fac_nested = FALSE,  # Specify if "wk2" is nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 8) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = "bait",
                                fac_random = FALSE,
                                fac_nested = FALSE,  # Specify if "bait" is nested or independent
                                cont_effects = "lengthWidth")
  } else if (mod == 9) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = NULL,
                                fac_random = NULL,
                                fac_nested = NULL,
                                cont_effects = "lengthWidth")
  } else if (mod == 10) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("C", "N"),
                                factors = c("class", "bait"),
                                fac_random = c(FALSE, FALSE),
                                fac_nested = c(FALSE, FALSE),  # Specify if factors are nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  }
}


# Run the models
source <- vector("list", n.mod)
discr <- vector("list", n.mod)
jags.mod<-vector("list", n.mod)

# Load modified output_JAGS.R
#source("output_JAGS.R")
#####
library(parallel)
ncores <- detectCores()
start <- Sys.time()
cl <- makeCluster(ncores, type = "PSOCK")
clusterExport(cl, c("source", "discr", "mix", "source.filename",
                    "mix.filename", "discr.filename", "output_JAGS"), envir = environment())
clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(MixSIAR)
  library(tidyr)
  library(R2jags)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(switchr)})

jags.mod <- parLapply(cl, seq_len(n.mod), function(mod) {
  # Rest of your code for processing each model
})


# Run the JAGS model
# MCMC run options:
# run <- "test"       # chainLength=1000, burn=500, thin=1, chains=3, calcDIC=TRUE
# run <- "normal"     # chainLength=100000, burn=50000, thin=50, chains=3, calcDIC=TRUE
# run <- "long"       # chainLength=300000, burn=200000, thin=100, chains=3, calcDIC=TRUE
# Can also set custom MCMC parameters
# run <- list(chainLength=700000, burn=300000, thin=500, chains=3, calcDIC=TRUE)
# ... (previous code)
# Create a list to store results for all models
jags.mod_list <- vector("list", n.mod)



for (mod in models) {
  cat("Processing model", mod, "\n")
  
  # Load the source data
  cat("Loading source data...\n")
  source[[mod]] <- load_source_data(filename = source.filename, mix = mix[[mod]], source_factors = NULL, conc_dep = FALSE, data_type = "means")
  
  cat("Loading discrimination data...\n")
  discr[[mod]] <- load_discr_data(filename = discr.filename, mix[[mod]])
  
  cat("Creating plots...\n")
  plot_data(filename = paste0("isospace_plot_", mod),
            plot_save_pdf = FALSE,
            plot_save_png = TRUE,
            mix[[mod]], source[[mod]], discr[[mod]], 
            return_obj = TRUE)
  
  model_filename <- paste0("MixSIAR_model_", mod, ".txt")
  resid_err <- TRUE
  process_err <- TRUE
  
  cat("Writing JAGS model...\n")
  write_JAGS_model(model_filename, resid_err, process_err, mix[[mod]], source[[mod]])
  
  cat("Running JAGS model...\n")
  jags.mod_list[[mod]] <- run_model(run = "normal", mix[[mod]], source[[mod]], discr[[mod]], model_filename, alpha.prior = 1)
  
  cat("Processing model", mod, "completed.\n")
  
  cat("Outputting JAGS results...\n")
  output_JAGS(jags.mod, mix[[mod]], source[[mod]], output_options = list(
    summary_save = TRUE,
    summary_name = "summary_statistics",
    sup_post = TRUE,
    plot_post_save_pdf = FALSE,
    plot_post_name = "posterior_density",
    sup_pairs = TRUE,
    plot_pairs_save_pdf = FALSE,
    plot_pairs_name = "pairs_plot",
    sup_xy = TRUE,
    plot_xy_save_pdf = FALSE,
    plot_xy_name = "xy_plot",
    gelman = TRUE,
    heidel = FALSE,
    geweke = TRUE,
    diag_save = TRUE,
    diag_name = "diagnostics",
    indiv_effect = FALSE,
    plot_post_save_png = TRUE,
    plot_pairs_save_png = TRUE,
    plot_xy_save_png = TRUE,
    diag_save_ggmcmc = FALSE,
    return_obj = TRUE
  ))
  
  cat("Model", mod, "processed.\n")
}

return(jags.mod)

  


save.image("Jan102023.RData")
elapsed <- Sys.time() - start
stopCluster(cl)
elapsed
```

I put the entire script, but the issue is during the processing of the models. I am new to stack overflow, so if there needs to be clarification, just ask. Thank you!

Output from

```
(head)jags.mod_list
[[1]]
             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
 [1,] -2.02751274 -1.8534157  0.74244925  0.75904805
 [2,] -0.67823940  0.6946821  0.03373757  0.76693203
 [3,] -0.53808848 -0.2355431 -1.74416979  0.01584072
 [4,] -1.21549451 -0.1253006  0.49359771 -0.13453093
 [5,]  0.73264459  0.2497470 -0.61351664 -0.76239776
 [6,]  0.10241967  2.4469685 -0.06161915  0.68925911
 [7,] -1.36381848 -0.6772546  0.44465907 -2.03137276
 [8,]  1.11880262  0.4045706 -1.97037086 -0.81809355
 [9,]  0.06827077 -1.9398904 -0.67898185 -0.39873061
[10,] -0.19356152  0.7909228 -1.09475686 -0.71850062

[[2]]
             [,1]         [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
 [1,]  0.28197727 -0.255549938 -0.6725137 -0.4545556
 [2,]  1.02319044  0.650949893  0.8341459 -0.2810962
 [3,]  1.67675837 -1.649001106 -1.0392340  0.6214326
 [4,] -0.06403873  0.004391174  0.1549689 -1.2640158
 [5,] -1.75280912 -0.266413353 -0.7673379 -0.5487489
 [6,]  0.79487900  0.139277827  0.8495898 -0.4301566
 [7,] -0.63821471  0.578749358 -0.2413500 -0.6120148
 [8,] -2.44352128  1.608233949  1.3490372 -0.8359704
 [9,]  0.84143723 -0.935263657  0.2078679 -0.3534304
[10,]  0.35337169 -0.106679545  0.6478205  1.2043776

[[3]]
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
 [1,]  1.1101569 -2.14722598 -0.3349421 -0.9714280
 [2,] -0.1180279 -0.73856746 -0.1986672  0.2550604
 [3,]  0.2857189  0.05830403  0.1508088 -0.1125553
 [4,]  0.3968538 -0.93095299  0.3033625 -1.1156963
 [5,] -1.0669476 -0.71029939 -1.7308263 -0.1770231
 [6,]  0.5011512  0.12220295  0.3201211 -0.6849134
 [7,] -0.1196506  0.84485150 -0.9630414 -0.3919226
 [8,] -0.5389890 -0.66470501  0.6417755  0.1449732
 [9,]  1.2877205 -1.43140177 -0.5091565  2.0412890
[10,]  0.5343739  0.42053666 -0.4346800  1.0318832

[[4]]
            [,1]       [,2]         [,3]        [,4]
 [1,] -0.2609358 -1.2219304  0.399218738  0.12965158
 [2,] -1.3200808  1.2167352  0.243446534 -0.58844476
 [3,]  0.4438083  0.2456863  1.724199898  1.68589830
 [4,]  1.0478528 -0.9356109 -2.874266111  0.74872969
 [5,] -0.1097809  0.2364836 -0.927213384 -1.13045073
 [6,] -1.0498342 -0.6321521 -0.672170174 -1.44435757
 [7,]  0.5278354  0.1992402  0.555827027  0.09275208
 [8,] -0.1478556  0.4368908  0.014619315 -1.84325835
 [9,]  0.2422065 -1.3346787  1.136946600  0.33440355
[10,] -0.2998031  0.3133390 -0.003638895  0.21576900

[[5]]
             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
 [1,]  0.06632457  0.3476482  1.6552105 -0.16958219
 [2,] -0.33823773  0.9511254 -1.1243460  0.59377474
 [3,]  0.62033689 -0.9968334  0.5292719 -0.82275144
 [4,]  0.96982186 -1.5943779 -0.3307577 -1.48190674
 [5,] -0.94080201 -1.8345736  0.9826169 -0.90589461
 [6,] -0.56724623  1.1997568 -0.6104444  0.07756049
 [7,] -0.50232604  0.3781853  1.2801526  0.90016583
 [8,]  1.36936467 -0.5515983  0.2993824  0.42378687
 [9,] -0.27806067  0.1385889 -1.1224587 -1.08475712
[10,]  0.50542675 -1.1676822  0.6920594  0.34415188

[[6]]
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
 [1,]  0.7906896  0.2746379 -0.91767214 -0.38164442
 [2,]  0.0248203  1.4233927  0.45606818  0.97122138
 [3,] -0.3960552  1.6258055 -0.58933335 -1.71563082
 [4,]  1.3475559  0.3962262 -0.80865391 -3.62693598
 [5,] -0.3194598  0.3646116  0.83649068  1.19569549
 [6,]  0.4870660  0.3511072 -0.26595540  0.85188427
 [7,] -3.0110953  0.1304655 -0.81151538 -0.53018314
 [8,] -2.5883576 -1.2094004 -0.22120124  0.48072528
 [9,] -0.3032784  1.4047228  0.06167054  2.08427841
[10,] -0.3648688 -0.8403785  1.11864603  0.05122416
```

Comment: Hello! A couple questions to help you move get your question answered. (1) When you say that you're getting the warning during the processing of models, at what lines in your code is that? (2) If the issue is during processing, are you getting samples from the posterior that look reasonable? (3) Could you share a subsets of the posteriors and/or other data for processing? If you can't share those, could you simulate data? For example `n=10; jags.mod_list <- list(); for(i in 1:n){jags.mod_list [[i]]<-as.matrix(replicate(4,rnorm(10,0,1)))}` to simulate the posterior if normally distributed.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply, let me answer your questions....(1) it is where the loop begins for running the model (start:for (mod in models) {), (end: return(jags.mod). (2) It will only iterate through the first model, the current jags.mod_list has been edited into the original post. Let me know how else I can help...

Comment: @gregor-fausto, sorry I forgot to tag you.

Comment: Thanks for more details. In addition to `jags.mod_list`, the loop also uses `source.filename` and `discr.filename`. Since these are on your local machine, folks here won't be able to run the code to help identify the issue. You'll want to include something that can be run in R by someone else. You could have some simulated data, share a public link, or output something that can be copied into R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. You may have trouble getting specific answers until the code can be run by someone else.

Comment: In the meantime, some other suggestions to help diagnose the issue. (1) In the line `for(mod in models){`, what is `models`? It sounds like it should be 1:10 but I don't see it defined in the script. (2) Try reducing the complexity of the problem. Instead of starting with 10 models, see if you can get your code to work with one model. (3) For example, for `mod=1` run the code in the loop line by line until you hit the error.  If that works, then set `mod=2` and run the code form the top of the loop, going line by line again until you hit the error.

Comment: @gregor-fausto. Here is the link to the GitHub page with the example data https://github.com/brianstock/MixSIAR/blob/master/inst/extdata/wolves_sources.csv. You can use wolves_sources.csv for source.filename, wolves_discrimination.csv for discr.filename, and wolves_consumer.csv for mix.filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced the script below with the `wolves` data that comes with the MixSIAR package. Some notes:

- I've replaced the mixture, source, and discrimination/TDF data that you used with the ones from the package. This means that I also had to change some of the variables in `load_mix_data`. For example, in model 1, `iso_names = c("d13C","d15N"), factors = "Region"`.
- I reduced the problem 2 models to speed things up.
- I deleted lines that were commented out for legibility.
- I changed the statement in the for loop to be `mod in 1:n.mod`.
- I couldn't get `plot_data()` to work yet so skipped that for now.
- The function `output_JAGS` previously had `jags.mod` as the JAGS model object (output from the JAGS model fit). I replaced that with `jags.mod_list[[mod]]`.

Update: I ran this with more than 2 models and it worked for me. I still am having trouble with the `plot_data` function so that remains commented out.

```
# reproducible example
library(MixSIAR)
library(tidyr)
library(R2jags)
library(ggplot2)

# load data files for mixture, source, and discrimination data
# Replace the system.file call with the path to your file
mixsiar.dir <- find.package("MixSIAR")

# mixture data
mix.filename <- system.file("extdata", "wolves_consumer.csv", package = "MixSIAR")

# source data
source.filename <- system.file("extdata", "wolves_sources.csv", package = "MixSIAR")

# discrimination/tdf data
discr.filename <- system.file("extdata", "wolves_discrimination.csv", package = "MixSIAR")

n.mod <- 2

mix <- vector("list", n.mod)
# Define each model
for (mod in 1:n.mod) {
  if (mod == 1) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("d13C","d15N"),
                                factors = NULL,
                                fac_random = NULL,
                                fac_nested = NULL,  # Specify if factors are nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } else if (mod == 2) {
    mix[[mod]] <- load_mix_data(filename = mix.filename,
                                iso_names = c("d13C","d15N"),
                                factors = "Region",
                                fac_random = c(FALSE),
                                fac_nested = c(FALSE),  # Specify if "sex" is nested or independent
                                cont_effects = NULL)
  } 
}


# Run the models
source <- vector("list", n.mod)
discr <- vector("list", n.mod)
jags.mod<-vector("list", n.mod)

#####
library(parallel)
ncores <- detectCores()
start <- Sys.time()
cl <- makeCluster(ncores, type = "PSOCK")
clusterExport(cl, c("source", "discr", "mix", "source.filename",
                    "mix.filename", "discr.filename", "output_JAGS"), envir = environment())
clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(MixSIAR)
  library(tidyr)
  library(R2jags)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(switchr)})

jags.mod <- parLapply(cl, seq_len(n.mod), function(mod) {
  # Rest of your code for processing each model
})

# Create a list to store results for all models
jags.mod_list <- vector("list", n.mod)


for (mod in 1:n.mod) {
  cat("Processing model", mod, "\n")
  
  # Load the source data
  cat("Loading source data...\n")
  source[[mod]] <- load_source_data(filename = source.filename, mix = mix[[mod]], source_factors = NULL, conc_dep = FALSE, data_type = "means")
  
  cat("Loading discrimination data...\n")
  discr[[mod]] <- load_discr_data(filename = discr.filename, mix[[mod]])
  
  ## I couldn't get plot_data to work so skipping it for now
  # cat("Creating plots...\n")
  # plot_data(filename = paste0("isospace_plot_", mod),
  #           plot_save_pdf = FALSE,
  #           plot_save_png = FALSE,
  #           mix = mix[[mod]], source = source[[mod]], discr = discr[[mod]], 
  #           return_obj = TRUE)
  
  model_filename <- paste0("MixSIAR_model_", mod, ".txt")
  resid_err <- TRUE
  process_err <- TRUE
  
  cat("Writing JAGS model...\n")
  write_JAGS_model(model_filename, resid_err, process_err, mix[[mod]], source[[mod]])
  
  cat("Running JAGS model...\n")
  jags.mod_list[[mod]] <- run_model(run = "test", mix[[mod]], source[[mod]], discr[[mod]], model_filename, alpha.prior = 1)
  
  cat("Processing model", mod, "completed.\n")
  
  cat("Outputting JAGS results...\n")
  output_JAGS(jags.mod_list[[mod]], mix[[mod]], source[[mod]], output_options = list(
    summary_save = TRUE,
    summary_name = "summary_statistics",
    sup_post = TRUE,
    plot_post_save_pdf = FALSE,
    plot_post_name = "posterior_density",
    sup_pairs = TRUE,
    plot_pairs_save_pdf = FALSE,
    plot_pairs_name = "pairs_plot",
    sup_xy = TRUE,
    plot_xy_save_pdf = FALSE,
    plot_xy_name = "xy_plot",
    gelman = TRUE,
    heidel = FALSE,
    geweke = TRUE,
    diag_save = TRUE,
    diag_name = "diagnostics",
    indiv_effect = FALSE,
    plot_post_save_png = TRUE,
    plot_pairs_save_png = TRUE,
    plot_xy_save_png = TRUE,
    diag_save_ggmcmc = FALSE,
    return_obj = TRUE
  ))
  
  cat("Model", mod, "processed.\n")
}

return(jags.mod)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am running it now to see if it works for me.

Comment: @gregor_fausto this worked, thank you!

Comment: @ElleryVincent Great! I added my comments to an issue on the Github repo for the package for the error I am getting with `plot_data`. https://github.com/brianstock/MixSIAR/issues/127 If it happens for you too, that might be another place to check.